# Deduce that there is a cup product that is well-defined

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have showed that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are closed forms on a smooth manifold $M$, then $\alpha \wedge \beta$ also be closed. Further, if one of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is exact, than $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is exact.

Than the question ask me to deduce that for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are closed forms whose cohomology classes are $[\alpha]$ and $\beta$ respectively, there is a well-define cup product

$$\cup :H^p(M) \times H^q(M) \to H^{p+q}(M)$$

given by $[\alpha]\cup[\beta]=[\alpha \wedge \beta]$

Is the question ask me to show that $[\alpha]\cup[\beta]=[\alpha \wedge \beta]$  is well-defined only? So I pick $[\alpha]=[\alpha^\prime]$ and $[\beta]=[\beta^\prime]$ so that $\alpha = \alpha^\prime +\text{d}a$ and $\beta= \beta^\prime +\text{d}b$ respectively. And work my way through to show that

$$[\alpha]\cup[\beta]=[\alpha \wedge \beta]=[(\alpha^\prime +\text{d}a)\wedge(\beta^\prime +\text{d}b)]= \cdots = [\alpha^\prime]\cup[\beta^\prime]$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what you're asked to show.